# How can I generate a tree with duplicate values

Tags: c#, python, c, tree, duplicates

I need to generate a tree in which a node can have some particular children, but the number of the node cannot repeat in the same branch.

```
1:5
2:5
3:5
4:5
5:1,2,3,4
Where ':' means that node n can have the children x,y,z,...
The root is 0, has all the possible children, but does not repeat in the tree.
                                    0
     /              /               |               \           \
    1               2               3               4             5
    |               |               |               |        /  /  \  \
    5               5               5               5       1   2   3   4
  / | \           / | \           / | \           / | \
2   3   4       1   3   4       1   2   4       1   2   3
```

Comment: Your problem definition is ambiguous.  What "5" vertex should be used with an edge definition of "4:5"?

Comment: 5 can gave 1,2,3,4 as children while the other nodes can only have 5 as a child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do a for loop from one to five and have an if inside the loop to see if the child is the same as the node you are on (the parent), then if it is, use continue to skip it.

If it can't repeat in the whole branch, then you have to check the grand-parent node too, in fact, all the ancestor nodes. You could do this with a while loop inside the main for loop. Loop until the ancestor node you are checking is not 0. Inside the while loop, you need to set the ancestor to the ancestor's parent.

This will "recurse" (call itself) making each new level down until all the numbers in a particular branch are used up.

Pseudo-code:

```
void makeTree() 
{
  addNode(0, null);
}

function node addNode(nodeNumber, parent) 
{
  nodeCollection nodes;
  if (parent != null)
    nodes = parent.nodes;
  else
    nodes = tree.nodes;

  node addNode = nodes.add(nodeNumber);
  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
  {
    bool alreadyexists = false;
    node ancestor = addNode;
    while (ancestor != null)
    {
      if (ancestor == childNode)
      {
        alreadyExists = true;
        break;
      }
      ancestor = ancestor.parent;
    }
    if (!alreadyExists) 
      addNode(childNode, addNode);
  }
}
```